# Secure my wifi with page asking for password

Tags: security, wifi, router, password-protection

I want to set up a home page when people connect to my wifi, and there ask for a username and password and depending on the answer connect them or not, to the wifi.

What do I have to do? Or how is this call, to search it up on internet that I couldn't find it.

Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of page is called a 'Captive Portal' and is a common feature of Wi-Fi APs and some Internet gateways.

It's considered poor user experience and generally does not add much in terms of security and access control over what Wi-Fi provides.